# Loading a document inside C# form

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to load a document ( The doc can be of any format) preview inside a windows form.

I Checked the IPreviewHandler but did know how to set it up.([HERE](https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/79))
This error is shownw when selecting a file:
[image]
I am using now the web control, however the txt files and the images are loaded inside the web.but pdf and office docs are loaded outside it ( like that I called Process.start(filename)

Why they are loaded outside? and is there another way to preview docs inside the winforms?

dot net 4 and VS 2015.

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: `IPreviewHandler` is the obvious route to go here, but we have no idea *what you tried* and so *why* it "did not work".

Comment: sorry , link was missed..I added it

Comment: That doesn't really add much because we still don't know which, if any, of those examples you actually tried to use and you still haven't explained what you mean by "did not work".

Comment: the doc just not loaded with no errors..do you have any code to test?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I updated the link.. I just do not know how to wrap it up, if  u can help please.

Comment: @PlexisPlexis post your *code* and the actual error, not screenshots. That error says there's no class registered with that Class ID. This means there's probably no preview handler registered for that file type. The OS uses the same registry keys to find which application to launch when you execute `Process.Start("some.docx")`. If the application itself hasn't registered a preview handler, you won't get a preview.

Comment: Preview handlers are used to display thumbnails in folders (among other things). Can you see any thumbnails for the file types you want? If not, there's probably no preview handler instaleld